# Saving Custom Fields on request

Tags: php, magento

I am new to the forum and have little time for magento development , 'm a programmer in a company and a customer states that his shop has a selection of the delivery date on the product page, add to cart before him , and that this option follow further up the order, he put into the administrator needs to manage holidays, days in advance of the application all set for a csv with her ​​affiliated stores , I managed to create a module and do it however I ended up with a big problem , I can not save the two fields that need to save are in the product page ( zip code and date) in the order in theory would be fields that can be changed like the qty ( quantity) and would have to be transferred to the session / cookie yet saved, and this is the big problem , unable to somehow save these fields , in practice I would have to double the qty field changing its name and save it in the application ( creating a new field in db ) this was the only solution I found but still unable .

This is a link to a product in the store with two fields : "http://foxflores.com.br/inde.php/caixa-de-chocolates-ferrero-rocher-super-luxo"

someone would have a light for me to save these fields in order?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, then you added that two fields, to the template only yet. And you want to save those two fields, against the items, as I assume the customer could add to the cart multiple items also.
The easiest solution is, that you create for the products, two custom options in the backend (Magento), you hide those fields, in the template with css, and write the value of your custom fields into them.(You can do this with js). Let me know if you need a help with the js.

With this, your fields values will be saved against each orderitem, in magento.

EDIT on 12/02/2014

Yes, you can add the custom option in the Magento admin , Manage product section. See image.
[image]

After this is added: You can add something like this to the frontend to copy over the values, from your custom field, to this newly generated fields.

```
    $('options_1_text').observe(
  'change', function () {
      var val = this.value;
        $("yourcustomfieldid1").value=val;

  });
```

Of course you need to edit the element ids to get it working. And you need to hide the newly created fields on the frontend.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, you can show me a example of this JS, and the custom options you sayed is the field i can create in the product page or in general products options?

Comment: Modified my answer to show the code, and the place where could you add custom option.